# How to replace deprecated "num_docs_shared_outside_domain" metric

Tags: google-admin-sdk

On May 15th, 2017, three metrics will be removed from the Reporting API of the Google Apps Admin SDK:

- `num_docs_internally_visible`
- `num_docs_externally_visible`
- `num_docs_shared_outside_domain`

I use all of these metrics in a scripts that performs some audits of our G Suite domain.

The [migration docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/updated-drive-metrics) say to use `num_owned_items_with_visibility_shared_externally_delta` instead of `num_docs_shared_outside_domain` for instance, but I don't understand how a delta metric can be used as a replacement unless you keep track of the actual number from day zero on.

How do I get the number of externally shared documents as a total, not a delta value?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/updated-drive-metrics) given, `num_owned_items_with_visibility_shared_externally_delta` is the number of items within the user's domain account that are not public or visible to anyone with link, but shared explicitly either with users or groups outside the domain up to the date of the report. So I think you can use it to get the number of externally shared documents. Also it is stated in the [notice](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/updated-drive-metrics#comparison-changes) that differences in metrics calculations exist in these changes, so review the notes as well as [Key issues](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/updated-drive-metrics#key-issues) for relevant details.

Comment: I just had a look, and `num_owned_items_with_visibility_shared_externally_delta` is zero for every singly user in my domain, so not very helpful...